# How to create a parent resource in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

When using the AWS Api-Gateway service, I'd like to add a "parent" resource without deleting and rebuilding the resource structure. Specifically, I'd like to change this:

```
resource/name
resource/name
```

And add a "parent" resource to it (v1) without deleting and remaking the two "resource/name" resources, like this:

```
/v1
  /resource/name
  /resource/name
```

If it requires use of the CLI, what would an example command look like?

UPDATE:

Thanks for the great answer Ka Hou Ieong. Here are some notes on implementing it:

```
rest-api-id : Put the api id here. You can look it up with this command: aws apigateway get-rest-apis

resource-id : Put the id of the resource you'd like to move here. You can look it up with this command: aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id API-ID-HERE

replace : Leave this; it's the operation.

/parentId : Leave this. It refers to the "key" of the value that you'll replace.

<new parent resourceId> : Replace this with the ID of the parent you'd like.
```

Comment: Looks like it may be possible using the CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-resource.html

Comment: Turns out--with the basic parameters in use--"create-resource" creates a new child resource, but doesn't make new parent resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a resource with path part "/v1", then re-parent these resources by using the CLI tool or SDK.

Example cli command to reparent the resource

```
aws apigateway  update-resource \
    --rest-api-id rest-api-id \
    --resource-id resource-id \
    --cli-input-json "{\"patchOperations\" : [ 
          {
            \"op\" : \"replace\",
            \"path\" : \"/parentId\",
            \"value\" : \"<new parent resourceId>\"
          } 
    ]}"
```

Here is the cli tool documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-resource.html

Here is the API reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/resource-update/